# Java Selenium iterate list by li

Tags: java, list, selenium, html-lists

I'm tried to iterate list from webside.
id separated line is ie

```
//*[@id="lista-wiersz-74813704"]
```

Number is different so in my opinion I can't use it.

Separate webelement is:

```
<li id="lista-wiersz-74779144" class = "linkDoKarty ogloszenie clearOver wyroznione standard" data-gtm="zajawka" data-pozycja="6" data-punkty-wyroznienia="2" data-ogloszenie="{'id_ogl':'74779144','id_kat':'397','polozenie':'lista'}".</li>
```

My code is:

```
WebElement offerList= driver.findElement(By.className("//@name='[linkDoKarty ogloszenie clearOver wyroznione standard]'"));
    List<WebElement> offerLists=offerList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for (WebElement offer : offerLists) {
        System.out.print("Value: "+offer.getText());
       }
```

but my code doesn't working.
id "lista wiersz.." is different in each one,
So I trying to use class but I see that I use it in wrong way

Comment: Did you mean to use `By.xpath(...)` on the first line? "//@name='...'" looks like an xPath locator.

Comment: Yes I have tried xpath, name, className. I don;t know how to use "id" when id is different  in each li (numer) so I haven't use.

Comment: I'm trying to find solutionns - I know how to use xpath from the "static" page. the website is http://dom.gratka.pl/mieszkania-sprzedam/lista/,,40,d_60,lubelskie,8,li,sr,lok,s.html. "linkDoKarty" is not xpath I don't know what it is.

Comment: Using the following in the browser console at that url gives me back 40 results:

`document.querySelectorAll("li[id^='lista-']")`

That's a CSS selector, but the idea is similar to Andrew_Allison's answer below. Have you tried that suggestion? What sort of error do you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

The good thing is that each `li` tag has an id with a common prefix which is `lista-wiersz-`. 
You could try changing :

```
List<WebElement> offerLists=offerList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

to

```
List<WebElement> offerLists = offerList.findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'lista-wiersz-')]"));
```